# Will ConcurrentHashMap with concurrencyLevel as 1 work as HashMap

Tags: java

I created a `ConcurrentHashMap with following values :

```
ConcurrentHashMap<String,String> concurrentHashMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<>(10,.9F,1);
```

Above means only 1 thread can update the map at a given point of time. If this is the case then can I say that it will work like `HashMap` in case of concurrency .i.e.; only one write operation will be performed at a given point of time.

Is my understanding correct or am I missing something here?

Answer (score 2):

The `concurrencyLevel` is just a hint, to help size internal data structures. There's no guarantee `1` would be the actual value used, and rather than behaving as a regular HashMap it may mean it would be less efficient to use if you actually used it from more than 1 thread.

From the Javadoc:

> Using a significantly higher value than you need can waste space and time, and a significantly lower value can lead to thread contention.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is actually about the [`concurrencyLevel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html#ConcurrentHashMap-int-float-int-):

> concurrencyLevel - the estimated number of concurrently updating threads. The implementation may use this value as a sizing hint.

Basically, a `ConcurrentHashMap` is chunked into segments. Each segment can only be modified by one thread at a time. Simply put, the more segments you have, the more concurrency you get. Yet you also end up using much more memory because each segment has its own memory overhead.

Therefore if you know that only one thread will access your map, setting the `concurrencyLevel` to 1 will only create 1 segment in the map, thus making it more memory-efficient.

If the value is too high, more memory will be used and some time will be used *finding* the right segment for every object you want to read/write in the map.